# "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main" when i use addView in loop

Tags: java, android

I was getting a "`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main`" when I try to create multiple `LinearLayout` using loop and adding a view to each of it.

```
void AMainViewBox(List<ViewBox> viewBoxList,View v){

    for (int i = 0; i < viewBoxList.size(); i++){

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        layoutParams.setMargins(0,20,0,0);
        layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        for(int j = 0; j < viewBoxList.get(i).getViewBoxTextList().size(); j++){
                textView = viewBoxList.get(i).getViewBoxTextList().get(j);
                layout.addView(textView);
        }

        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(0,20,0,0);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);



        Log.d("vbl",""+layout);
        myLayout.addView(layout);
    }
}
```

**When I add a try catch a error only the first value in index is working**

```
void AMainViewBox(List<ViewBox> viewBoxList,View v){

    for (int i = 0; i < viewBoxList.size(); i++){

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        layoutParams.setMargins(0,20,0,0);
        layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        for(int j = 0; j < viewBoxList.get(i).getViewBoxTextList().size(); j++){
            try {
                textView = viewBoxList.get(i).getViewBoxTextList().get(j);
                layout.addView(textView);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("err", "error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(0,20,0,0);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);



        Log.d("vbl",""+layout);
        myLayout.addView(layout);
    }
}
```

**My output when I put a try catch**

[image: my output when I put a try catch]

Comment: please add your complete stack trace - `"E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main"` this doesn't really say anything useful

Answer (score 0):

How we should help you by such question?

When you create a question, on left side you can see the helps to provide the informations, to help understand the problem

[image]

In your question you say:
When I add a try catch a error only the **first value** in index is **working**

Thats already an answer for your question. You have found, where the problem is.

How we should now help you?

expand your try catch with logs

```
try {
      if (viewBoxList.get(i) == null) {
          System.out.println("empty item at i = " + i);
      }
      if (viewBoxList.get(i).getViewBoxTextList() == null) {
          System.out.println("empty textlist at i = " + i);
      }
      if (viewBoxList.get(i).getViewBoxTextList().get(j) == null) {
          System.out.println("empty textlist item at i = " + i);
      }
      textView = viewBoxList.get(i).getViewBoxTextList().get(j);
      layout.addView(textView);
}
```

and look in logs.